# How to handle CSS animations efficiently

Tags: css

IMHO there are 3 possible ways to declare an animation for certain HTML elements on the page:

1. `* { transition: all .3s ease; }` - Regarding lines of code, file size, and ease of use, I find this the most suiting  solution to handle CSS animations on a page. But I do know using the asterisk selector has quite a heavy impact on performance, so this option doesn't seem like the most efficient one. Also, this sometimes causes for unwanted animations on objects where it's not needed.
2. `.animated { transition: all .3 ease; }` - Again regarding lines of code, file size and ease of use (in CSS), this looks like the optimal solution. We create a class specifically for animations, and just add this class to all elements we need an animation on. Variations can be made (adjusting the speed etc.) with other classes. But, this does require that every single HTML element you would like to animate should get this class, which means that when for some reason the classname changes one day, all these references should be updated.
3. `.class1, .class2, .class3, ... { transition: all .3s ease; }` - Another solution to this problem could be to have one giant selector for every HTML element in need of animation. This could be causing a giant CSS selector, which is not very file size friendly, nor very readable IMO. But, it does have some advantages too - there's only one place to be updated whenever an element needs animation.

So my question is:

**What is the most efficient way to handle CSS animations on a HTML page?**

Comment: Not using `*` or `all`combined with method 2. Being specific about animations will improve performance. If the system knows it only has to animate the `height`, it will optimise for that. So being more specific is good here: `.animate-height { transition: height .3s ease; }`

Comment: Which would mean that I would have to create different animation classes for different animations, and adding these classes to all elements needing animation. Is that really the most optimal way? It does sound like a bit of overkill to me, but I could be wrong. I do agree on being more specific improving performance though.

Comment: Using `*` and `all` is _not_ overkill? Don't forget that many of these things get handled by the GPU, leading to more animations needed to be calculated. It's more work for you, yes, but if you are talking quality and performance in the browser this is the way to go. You don't need a rule for everything, and also, you don't need or even want to animate everything. If you just want everything to simply transition, then you're not designing your front-end, you're just lazily adding flash-bang.

Comment: I have a feeling your idea of efficiency isn't the same as ours here...

Comment: Well there's the developers point of view, and the performance point of view AFAIK. I'm trying to get the best of both worlds :-)

Comment: Well, using `*` and `all` together are *terrible* for runtime performance.